# Einstein Predictive Email Reccomendations (Marketing Cloud) customization by Country

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, einstein, einstein-recommendations

We are trying to implement Marketing Cloud Email Recommendations: we have a global product catalog we would like to upload, the problem is the availability (together with the discount) must not be unique (global) since it should differ by country.

We would like to recommend only products that are available in the country of the subscriber and with the discount which is applied in that country (every country has different availability and discount related to a same product - skuid).

Has anyone faced this issue? Support told us we would need to have different BUs for the different countries but it is not a viable option. 
Could it be possible to use Rules to limit visibility? In this case where could we store information?

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 4):

the main answer to your problem are localized product catalog fields:
[Localization Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_localized_recommendations.htm&type=5)

Lets cover Availability:

I haven't tried it but i think that you cannot use localization options on the Availability field because its used to activate or deactive recommendations for that product over all recommendations.

What you would need to do is create either a Country_Availability that stores the countries where it is available seperated by ~. Then something like USA~MEX~CAN or whatever is in that field and you would use this inside the recommendation engine create rules like the following:

- Events and Attributes - Custom Attribute - Country (you need to insert it inside the predictive calls of a subscriber on your website inside setuserdetails) Includes MEX
- Actions - Include Items with Country_Availability contains MEX

And then create multiple rules for every country you have.

Maybe it is also possible to create localized availability fields but i am uncertain if these can be used inside rule manager.

Let us cover discount:

For discount you would need to create localized discount columns in your product catalog. Then create displays etc.. and use it inside the email. But you will need to write AMPScript to concat localization parameter to the recommendation call inside the email like "?locale=fr-fr" dynamically from the subscriberattributes you have. Remember you will need to have every field you want to display localized in a localized column inside the product catalog (also productnames etc).

Therefore your Einstein recommendation blocks need to be rewritten inside its HTML.

The other option is to code the localization option static into content blocks and use audiences that definitely only have that localization option. Therefore you would create a dynamic content block that has einstein content blocks inside of itself which have to be configured correctly by the rules from the dynamic content blocks.

I hope is what kind of understandable. If you have more questions or need clarification please comment on this post (or write per LinkedIn or Salesforce Collaboration Plattform, my name is always the same).

Before you might become angry from the process of the catalog image generation read this post:[Catalog Generation Process](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236286/how-to-get-an-working-automated-catalog-image-generation-for-einstein-email-reco)

Comment: Thank You for your response! I get the point for availability, its the same solution we were thinking of. Whilst for the discount: wouldn't it work fine if I create another custom attribute for each different discount per country (Discount_France) and use rules in order to show the correct discount for that country?

Comment: The thing is: if I use AMPScript I am kind of corrupting the intelligence by using a front-end solution, so the system is not aware of this tweak. While if I use rules the intelligence is somehow aware of the limitation and knows that it should produce recommendations taking into account those restrictions. Don't know if this makes sense...